# Multiple inputs triggering same observeEvent not working for button in modalDialog

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a minimal code below to reproduce the problem I am facing in my app.

What I am trying to do is call the same `observeEvent` for multiple inputs where one of the `actionButton` for `observeEvent` is present in `modalDialog` which only gets created after function which is called within the `observeEvent` is called. The problem I am facing is that after adding this `actionButton` from `modalDialog` to call the `observeEvent` with multiple inputs the `observeEvent` is never called. If I remove this button the `observeEvent` is called. The following is my code:

```
  library(shiny)

  #Function called from shiny server
  func <- function(input,output){
    if(is.null(input$txt_Modal)){

      output$txt <- renderText("No Text Entered Yet!")
      showModal(modalDialog(title = "Choose Survival Time",
                            textInput(inputId = "txt_Modal", "Enter text:"),
                            easyClose = FALSE, footer = actionButton(inputId = "btn_Modal_OK","OK")))
    }else{

      output$txt <- renderText({input$txt_Modal})
    }

  }

  ##UI code
  ui <- fluidPage(

    actionButton(inputId = "btn", label = "Enter function and Print Value"),
    textOutput(outputId = "txt")

  )

  ##Server code
  server <- function(input, output, session){

    observeEvent({
      input$btn
      input$btn_Modal_OK
    },{
      func(input, output)
    })


  }
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here `input$btn_Modal_OK` is the button that is created in the `ModalDialog` which is created within the function `func`. On removing `input$btn_Modal_OK` from the `observeEvent` the code works as expected.

The cause that I can think of why this is happening is because `input$btn_Modal_OK` is `NULL` at the start of the program. One method I can think to remove this error is to write a different `observeEvent` for `input$btn_Modal_OK` but my actual code has many lines of code within my `observeEvent` which I don't want to rewrite in another `observeEvent` and make the code bulky.

Please note that this is not what I am doing in my actual app, I have just written this code to reproduce the problem. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that `input$btn` switched from `NULL` to `0` on initialisation and triggered the modal, but you want `func` only to be triggered when `input$btn` is actually pressed, that is when it has a value of `1` or above. That's why this solves your problem:

```
observeEvent(c(input$btn, input$btn_Modal_OK), {
   validate(need(input$btn > 0, ''))
   func(input, output)
})
```

[image]